# Convert akka ByteString to Java InputStream?

Tags: java, scala, akka

In scala, how can an [`akka.util.ByteString`](https://doc.akka.io/api/akka/current/akka/util/ByteString.html) be converted to a [`java.io.InputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html)?

I tried the following:

```
val byteStringToInputStream : ByteString => InputStream = 
  byteStr => new ByteArrayInputStream(byteStr.asByteBuffer.array()))
```

But this results in an Exception being thrown

> java.nio.ReadOnlyBufferException
>     at java.nio.ByteBuffer.array(ByteBuffer.java:996)

Thank you in advance for your consideration and response.

Comment: Just curious. What is the reason of converting `ByteString` to oio `InputStream`. Interacting with some  java-io api?

Comment: @SomeName You are correct, I'm using a java API that I don't have control over.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
var byteArray = byteString.toArray()
var inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(byteArray)
```

P.S. not a `Scala` developer (but a `Java` one). Hope I got it right with syntax.